# Android scale view

Tags: android, animation, view, scale

I need to scale View by setting the scale factor in percents. I need to set exactly the same param as ScaleAnimation use, because I'm going to scale it using ScaleAnimation in the future. How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Does it really matter? All I'm asking is where is that scale factor located, so I can adjust it. I'm not looking for any other solution.

Comment: android:weight is the closest thing I am aware of

Comment: I'm not looking for the closest thing, but the exact thing. ScaleAnimation isn't using android:weight, it scales the whole canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by creating animation xml file with duration=0, which sets desired parameters. It is also possible to create such animation via code. Then to apply it, just use:

```
Animation animationInit = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.gallery_init);
v.startAnimation(animationInit);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to use straight up float values (percent) when handeling drawing and placements. Refer to:  [this lovely site which really helps with views.](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/)

```
public class MyView extends View {


    ...


    @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.scale((getWidth() > getHeight()) ? getHeight() : getWidth());

        // Your other code

        canvas.restore();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not the same method used as in ScaleAnimation. If I'd start animating such View, those 2 scale factors would be multiplied.